# How to create non-greedy regular expression from right?

Tags: python, regex

I have a file named 'ab9c_xy8z_12a3.pdf' . I want to capture part after the last underscore and before '.pdf'. 
Writing regular expression like :

```
    s = 'ab9c_xy8z_12a3.pdf'
    m = re.search(r'_.*?\.pdf',s)
    m.group(0)
```

returns:
'_xy8z_12a3.pdf'

In this example, I would like to capture only '12a3' part. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Instead of `.*?` use `[^_]*`

Comment: Thanks. I changed regex to `_([^_]*)\.pdf` and then used `m.group(1)` to get 12a3 as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`_.*?\.pdf` regex](https://regex101.com/r/ZyDRSl/3/debugger) matches the *first* underscore with `_`, then matches any 0+ chars other than a newline, as few as possible, but up to the leftmost occurrence of `.pdf`, which turns out to be at the end of the string. So, `.` matched all underscores on its way to `.pdf`, just because of the way a regex engine parses the string (from left to right) and due to `.` pattern.

You may fix the pattern by using a [**negated character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^_]` instead of `.` that will "subtract" underscores from `.` pattern.

```
([^_]+)\.pdf
```

and grab Group 1 value. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZyDRSl/2).

[Python demo](http://rextester.com/UVH93077):

```
import re
rx = r"([^_]+)\.pdf"
s = "ab9c_xy8z_12a3.pdf"
m = re.search(rx, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # => 12a3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.split` instead:

```
>>> re.split('[_.]', 'ab9c_xy8z_12a3.pdf')[-2]
'12a3'
```

Comment: Except you'd also need to verify the extension

Comment: True, I was assuming `s` was known to end with `pdf`. (You should post your comment as an answer, by the way.)